# How to speed up web scraping with nested urllib2.urlopen() in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping

I have the following code to gather the number of words there are in each chapter of a book. In a nutshell, it opens the url of each book, then the urls of each chapter associated with the book.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def scrapeBook(bookId):
    url = 'http://www.qidian.com/BookReader/'+str(bookId)+'.aspx'
    try:
        words = []
        html = urllib2.urlopen(url,'html').read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)           
        try:                             
            chapters = soup.find_all('a', rel='nofollow')  # find all relevant chapters
            for chapter in chapters:                       # loop through chapters
                if 'title' in chapter.attrs: 
                    link = chapter['href']                 # go to chapter to find words
                    htmlTemp = urllib2.urlopen(link,'html').read()
                    soupTemp = BeautifulSoup(htmlTemp)

                    # find out how many words there are in each chapter
                    spans = soupTemp.find_all('span')
                    for span in spans:
                        content = span.string
                        if not content == None:
                            if u'\u5b57\u6570' in content:
                               word = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", content)
                               words.append(word)
        except: pass

        return words

    except:       
        print 'Book'+ str(bookId) + 'does not exist'
```

Below is a sample run

```
words = scrapeBook(3501537)
print words
>> [u'2532', u'2486', u'2510', u'2223', u'2349', u'2169', u'2259', u'2194', u'2151', u'2422', u'2159', u'2217', u'2158', u'2134', u'2098', u'2139', u'2216', u'2282', u'2298', u'2124', u'2242', u'2224', u'178', u'2168', u'2334', u'2132', u'2176', u'2271', u'2237']
```

Without doubt the code is very slow. One major reason is that I need to open the url for each book, and for each book I need to open the url of each chapter. Is there a way to make the process faster?

Here is another bookId without empty return 3052409. It has hundreds of chapters, and the code runs forever.

Comment: you got to multithread http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: I like bs4 because it is really easy to use, but if performences matter, you should use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) which is much faster.

Comment: @Delgan it is possible to instruct bs4 to _use_ lxml.

Comment: @Delgan as the folks at bs4 [recommend](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).

Comment: @RishavKundu I was not aware about this, good to know, thank you!

Comment: @ Rishav Kundu Does that mean that I will pick up some speed after changing to a different parser?

Comment: @YeTian It will, but not much. Your main bottleneck is the network, not the parsing speed. See my linked question for suggestions on how to make it faster.

Comment: @RishavKundu   I understand your link, but I don't know how I can implement the method. There are two steps where I can potentially distribute the urls, i.e., at the book level or at the chapter level. Should I do both?

Comment: @Delgan we want MOAR SPEED!

Comment: @YeTian whichever one you do, the speed will increase.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you need to open each book and each chapter is dictated by the views exposed on the server. What you could do, it to implement parallel clients. Create a thread pool where you offload HTTP requests as jobs to the workers, or do something similar with coroutines.

Then there's the choice of the HTTP client library. I found `libcurl` and `geventhttpclient` more CPU efficient than `urllib` or any other of the python standard libs.

Comment: Is implementing parallel clients the same as running the same code (sequentially) on different terminals?

Comment: Essentially it's the same, you run a bunch of I/O bound jobs in parallel to make it faster. The difference is that a threadpool / coroutine implementation gives you the ease of a single point of entry.